# Disk driver when installing Ubuntu LTS 12.04 in VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player

I am attempting to install Ubuntu LTS 12.04 on a VMWare instance however am prompted with the following screen. I haven't been able to locate which driver Ubuntu should be using. I have tried vmw_pvscsi however haven't had any luck either.

[image]

**EDIT**

The following properties are set on the hard disk settings in VMWare

[image]

Comment: What disk interface is VMWare presenting to the VM? You should be able to find out by going into the VM's properties/settings.

Comment: @Steven Monday - I have updated my question with an additional screenshot.

Comment: I was hoping you'd see something a bit more specific than just "SCSI". Also, it's strange that the Ubuntu installer is not auto-detecting the SCSI driver it needs... What VMWare product are you using, specifically?

Comment: @Steven Monday - It's the latest version of VMPlayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [VMWare Player 4 docs (PDF, page 77)](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware_player40.pdf), you can use a virtual SCSI disk in a VM as long as the guest OS has a driver for either the "LSI Logic" or the "BusLogic" SCSI adapter. The doc goes on to say that "You determine which SCSI adapter to use when you create a virtual machine."

From your screenshot, the Ubuntu installer includes the BusLogic driver, so when you create your VM, specify the BusLogic adapter, and you should be good to go.